# Create 2^n combinations Python

Tags: python, combinations

I'm having a bit of trouble regarding a Python project I'm doing for school.  I have very little experience with Python, which is giving me some trouble in determining how to exactly solve this problem.
 
I need to create all possible states (combinations) of booleans of 2^n booleans.

So, for n=3, I would need to have represented: 
 
`(True, False, False)`
`(True, True, False)`
`(True, True, True)`
*etc*. Up to all 8 combinations.

But I really don't know how to go about doing this in python.  I know that there must be nested for loops, and that I would represent the combinations as lists of lists, but that's all I've come up with.  Any assistance?

Comment: Have you tried googling the title of your question?

Comment: Since the question has already been answered, it might be worth looking into `itertools`. It has many functions that are worth remembering during your study. They're explained too!

Comment: Just to be clear, that was the first hit.

Comment: I did do a Google search, but I now realise I must not have been very thorough.  I didn't use the most effective search terms; will strive not to jump the gun in the future.  Apologies, and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> n=3
>>> list(itertools.product([True, False], repeat=n))
[(True, True, True), (True, True, False), (True, False, True), (True, False, False), (False, True, True), (False, True, False), (False, False, True), (False, False, False)]
```

I know it would have been better to teach you how to fish, so may I suggest reading the [itertools docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), it comes handy quite often.